# Prove there are infinitely many integer solutions to $z^z = y^y x^x$ for with $x,y,z > 1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I have tried a number of methods using prime factorisations but they inevitably lead to invoking too many unknowns for me and balloon in complexity.

Comment: do u have any example for such numbers?

Comment: I do have some, and they were quite a challenge to find.

Comment: can u post any such numbers, just for curiosity,

Comment: This is an old problem of Erd\H{o}s, referenced in Guy's Unsolved Problems in Number Theory (D13). Chao Ko found infinitely many solutions, the smallest of which has $x=12^6$, $y = 6^8$ and $z=2^{11} 3^7$.